# how to store different different multiple response in one variable in react native javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am getting response like this =

```
Object {
  "city": "Nanekarwadi",
  "country": "India",
  "district": null,
  "isoCountryCode": "IN",
  "name": "PRXX+37P",
  "postalCode": "410501",
  "region": "Maharashtra",
  "street": null,
  "subregion": "Pune",
  "timezone": null,
}
```

Now I want to show my subregion, postal code, region these all three in Text Input field in editable format.
so How to do it.
Now I am trying like this

```
setCompleteAdd(response)   or setCompleteAdd(respone.subreg, res.city, res.code)
```

and in text input like this

```
<TextInput
value={CompleteAdd}
/>
```

But I know this is not gonna work. so please help . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how do you want to show these three objects if there is any specific format you wanted to show your state. For e.g: *Pune, Nanekarwadi, 410501*

Then save it like this:

```js
setCompleteAdd(`${response.subreg}, ${response.city}, ${response.code}`)
```

And show it to your `value` prop of `TextInput` like the same:

```js
<TextInput
   value={CompleteAdd}
   onChangeText={ setCompleteAdd }
/>
```

If any of the objects is `null` in your response then do like this in `useEffect` or anywhere you're getting your response:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if(!response.subregion){
      setCompleteAdd(`${response.city}, ${response.postalCode}`)
    }
    else if(!response.city){
      setCompleteAdd(`${response.subregion}, ${response.postalCode}`)
    }
    else if(!response.postalCode){
      setCompleteAdd(`${response.subregion}, ${response.city}`)
    }
    else if(!response.city && !response.subregion){
      setCompleteAdd(`${response.postalCode}`)
    }
    else if(!response.city && !response.postalCode){
      setCompleteAdd(`${response.subregion}`)
    }
    else if(!response.subregion && !response.postalCode){
      setCompleteAdd(`${response.city}`)
    }
    else if(response.postalCode && response.city && response.subregion){
      setCompleteAdd(`${response.subregion}, ${response.city}, ${response.postalCode}`)
    }
  }, [])
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: one more question I have.If there  is null value of city or region. then i dont want to show that value. please help

Comment: check my updated answer.

Comment: ok I  know this but I think if there is any easy way to do it. that why I asked you. anyway thanks